# SQL Problemas com query

Tags: sql, query

Estou a ter problemas com a seguinte query:

```
SELECT Cliente.Nome, (Reserva.NumeroNoites) TotalNoites 
From Reserva 
inner join Cliente on Reserva.ID_Cliente = Cliente.ID_Cliente 
group by Reserva.NumeroNoites, Cliente.Nome
```

Gostava de selecionar os clientes com o maior numero de noites...
Contudo ao fazer a minha query... o resultado é

> ```
> Cliente Barbosa : 1 noite;
> Cliente Silva: 1 noite;
> Cliente Silva: 2 noites;
> ```

Aqui está o problema... no grafico aparece 2 vezes o mesmo cliente ( Silva ) em que o correto seria aparecer apenas 1 vez com o total de 3 Noites.
Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Adiciona um SUM em Reserva.NumeroNoites!

Comment: Já adicionei e não funcionou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você não está somando o total de noites; o que está fazendo é apenas listar as noites e os clientes (assim, se o cliente tiver 10 reservas, será exibido 10 vezes). Tente a consulta abaixo:

```
SELECT Cliente.Nome, SUM(Reserva.NumeroNoites) as TotalNoites 
From Reserva 
inner join Cliente on Reserva.ID_Cliente = Cliente.ID_Cliente 
group by Cliente.Nome
```

Comment: Fogo, super pratico, é isso mesmo, resultado obtido com sucesso ! Muito obrigado !